# Possible to open Sublime in two row layout by default?

Tags: sublimetext3

As a matter of personal preference I like Sublime 3 to be set to a two row layout. I can set this through the menu or via keyboard shortcut, but I am wondering if it's possible to open every window in this layout by default? I can't find anything in the Default settings file that corresponds to the layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the layout of ST then [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami) is your friend.

Install it through Package Manager and you'll be able to do pretty amazing things with layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python (.py) file in your Packages\User folder like the one I have:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

def plugin_loaded ():
    sublime.active_window().run_command ("toggle_distraction_free")
    sublime.active_window().run_command ("set_layout", {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
})
```

The name of the file is not relevant. In my case, I like to start with two panes in distraction free mode.