# Open Sublime Text 3 with Two rows

Tags: sublimetext3

i have found this, but it doesn't work with Sublime Text 3:
[Possible to open Sublime in two row layout by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328340/possible-to-open-sublime-in-two-row-layout-by-default)

What I want is simply to open two rows, when i start sublime3.
The same thing, that happens when i click on View -> Layout -> Rows 2.

I would also like to open specific Files in the second row, but this is more or less a bonus.

the provided link is for 2 columns, not rows

br

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the sublime default View to 2 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513270/how-to-set-the-sublime-default-view-to-2-rows)

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144648/split-single-view-horizontally-in-sublime